# C# singleton definition

Tags: c#, singleton

I saw implementation like that:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static readonly MyClass _instance = new MyClass();

    public static MyClass Instance{
        get{ return _instance; }
    }
}
```

Why not make it simple?

```
class MyClass
{
    public static readonly MyClass Instance = new MyClass();
}
```

Comment: The only difference between given snippets of code is that in the first case `MyClass` will be instantiated "on demand".

Comment: [Jon Skeet's in depth explanation](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) Although your example doesn't include his private and static constructors (See example 4)

Comment: Why? From Java I know that once class is used in any way, the first thing that happens is that static fields get initialized. Isn't it the same in C#?

Comment: Oh... you are correct of course. I misread the first sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* expose public fields like this - but I prefer not to. If you leave it as a property, you can change the implementation later. For example, suppose you later add a static method which you want to be able to call without initializing the singleton - with the property version, you could change the code to:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass Instance { get { return InstanceHolder.instance; } }

    private MyClass() {}

    private static class InstanceHolder
    {
        internal static readonly MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    }

    public static void Foo()
    {
        // Calling this won't initialize the singleton
    }
}
```

(With the original version, the singleton *might* be initialized, or it might not be - it's up to the CLR.)

That's just *one* example of why you might want to change the implementation later. With a property, you can do that - with a field, you can't.

Comment: Yes, but you can always change field to a property and class users will not notice it. That way you make code simple in the beginning and add complications only when needed. Isn't that good?

Answer (score 2):

What you've got there would work fine, but public fields are usually frowned upon in favour of Properties.  You can change the implementation of the `get { ... }` without needing to change calling code.  This would enable you to (for example) switch to lazy initialisation where the Instance is only created the first time it is used.

Note that although the calling code wouldn't need to change, it would change the signature of your class since a readonly property is different to a readonly field.